# EWS Managed API with EXO - Folder.Emtpy against Purges folder - "The folder can't be emptied."

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to use EWS to clear out the Purges folder within Recoverable Items.  I'm successfully binding to the purges folder and can search items to confirm I'm definitely looking at that folder.

When I try to use the Folder.Empty method, using 0 (HardDelete) or 1 (SoftDelete), and in either of those cases either with 0/1 or $true/$false for the second parameter (delete subfolders), I always get back "The folder can't be emptied.".  If I supply 2 for the DeleteMode / 1st parameter, which means "MoveToDeletedItems", it successfully moves items back from Purges into the user-visible Deleted Items folder.  I can then successfully empty that folder with Folder.Empty(0,0), and then the items are back into the Purges folder, where again I experience the same behavior.

Does anyone know if this is even possible ever?  I've excluded the mailbox from a retention policy, then waited for DelayHoldApplied/DelayReleaseHoldApplied to become true (only the former did), and then did Set-Mailbox -RemoveDelayHoldApplied.  I've also *just* set SingleItemRecoveryEnable to $false.  I'm not sure if maybe the SingleItemRecoveryEnabled setting change is on the potential 240 minute delay, so I'll keep trying for the next 4 hours and post an update.  Hoping somebody has some factual knowledge about whether I should even be able to, ever, use the Folder.Empty or Item.Delete methods on the Purges folder (or its items).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Before I answer my own question, I'm going to just comment that indeed almost 4 hours went by (3 hours, ~55 minutes) before SingleItemRecoveryEnabled being set to $false took effect.  What I ended up having to do (which would never work with a large mailbox) was to do Folder.Empty(2,0), which means "MoveToDeletedItems", "Do not delete subfolders" on the Purges folder.  This moved items to the user-visible Deleted Items folder.  From there, I did Folder.Empty(0,0), "HardDelete", "Do not delete subfolders", against the Deleted Items folder, and this time those items bypassed the Purges folder.

Comment: Note that I did the monkey dance, bouncing items back and forth between Purges and Deleted Items, about 25 times during those ~4 hours of waiting.  So I can say with certainty that something changed at the ~4 hour mark, which most certainly is that Single Item Recovery being disabled finally took effect (the Set-Mailbox command gave warning that it might take "240 minutes".  It was bang on.

Comment: For future reference, I'll disable Single Item Recovery and wait 4 hours before going in and doing what I really need, which is to empty the DiscoveryHolds folder.

Comment: Last comment, and reason for not marking as Answered... MFCMAPI is able to empty the Purges folder no problem.  It didn't face any issues related to Single Item Recovery.  So I'm still interested to know why EWS' Folder.Empty isn't working.